# Google Photos API for Public Albums

Tags: google-photos-api

I have a website that the gallery part uses photos that are stored on Google Photos.

I'm trying to migrate a connection to the Picasa API (now completely depreciated) to Google Photos API. However all suggestions point to the visitor to authenticate themselves and exchange code for a token, however I'm looking for a simpler method that skips this for public shared photos and users without a Google account. Any suggestions?

PS: I'm using C# WebForms, but an API that returns a JSON would be great.